# django filter query / wildcard symbol in database

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a django model with a field `path`. This field could contain a wildcard at the end, for example like this: `/products/*`. Is there a single query solution that allows me to `.filter(path__specialmatch="/products/product-1/xy/")`?

My solution for now would be stripping segment after segment of the lookup path, and then check with an `.filter(path=remaining_segments + "*")`.

Is this possible with a single query instead?

Comment: You need to make your question more clear.

Comment: Could you use ```startswith```? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-startswith

Comment: I dont think, as you see above, `/products/*` doesnt starts with `/products/product-1/xy/`. but yes, I still hope that there is such an easy solution as `startswith` ;-)

Comment: Interesting question. Databases - and Django - support regex queries, where you pass a regex and get back rows containing strings that match. But you want the opposite of that, where you pass a string and get back any rows containing regexes that match. I don't know of any way of doing that directly.

Comment: thx @danielroseman , couldn't have said better! me neither knows, so I guess I'll be stripping segments for now. shouldn't be that expensive...will add a max amount of segments, though.

Comment: thanks all of you. see my answer for an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not possible.**

Just for reference: As this had to be used for a django redirects app, I've come across [django-robust-redirects](https://github.com/spothero/django-robust-redirects) that does it with a dynamic urls file (see middleware.py, utils.py). Though not answering my question, I'll let this stay for reference.

Comment: I'll wait some more until accepting this, for letting you prove me the contrary.